# Transformer info?

Tags: transformer

I can't information on this transformer looking at the info on the transformer. Is there anything to look up from this info? I plan on using this for a lab bench power supply. It was pulled out of an old surrounded sound unit.

[image]

Comment: Lots of pills people take are marked with little symbols that give (supposedly) some indication of what they are. Say you found one and used google to identify the pill as suitable for a headache, would you be confident of popping it? Or would you go to the nearest shop and buy a fresh packet?

Comment: Excellent!! I love popping random pills!  